# The "--no-migration" option does not exist in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have installed laravel 5 and looking for scaffolding but when i run this command

`php artisan make:scaffold Tweet --schema="title:string:default('Tweet #1'), body:text"`

it is giving exception "The "--no-migration" option does not exist".
I have checked it with `php artisan migrate --help` command and the option does not exists.
Can anybody help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see that flag in your command...

Comment: do you have --no-migration option ?@Half Crazed

Comment: I don't see a `make:scaffold` command on Laravel 5. Are you using a specific extension?

Comment: I have run following command - 1.composer require 'laralib/l5scaffold' --dev  2.

Comment: I am trying to install - Laravel 5 Scaffold Generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *laralib/l5scaffold* extension does not have a `--no-migration` option. So you cannot prevent creating the migration files via command.

Currently I don't see any suitable way to achieve the desired behaviour. Just delete the migration files afterwards.

---

Or implement the feature yourself and create a pull request to the [repository](https://github.com/laralib/l5scaffold). You will probably only need to change `src/Commands/ScaffoldMakeCommand.php`. Here are some hints:

```
public function fire()
{
    // ...

    // Generate files
    if (!$this->option('no-migration')) {
        $this->makeMigration();
    }
    $this->makeSeed();
    // ...
}

protected function getOptions()
{
    return [
        ['schema', 's', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Schema ...', null],
        ['form', 'f', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Use ...'],
        ['no-migration', 'm', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Don\'t create migration files.']
    ];
}
```